# How to create CSV and save it in a variable for further processing in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, function, csv

Facing kind of a mini challenge here today.

I want to create CSV string from a column in a table in postgresSQL using a SQL query inside a stored function and want to be able to store into another table as single value (and do further processing on that table).

### My database engine is postgreSQL.

I have seen lots of examples allowing the user to use COPY TO and COPY FROM but they either return to STDOUT or save to a file.

```
Copy (Select id From product limit 10) To STDOUT With CSV DELIMITER ',';
```

### Source Data:

```
Product
id | Name
10  | Product1
21  | Product1
34  | Product1
45  | Product1
17  | Product1
```

### Required/Target Data:

```
TempTable
value
10,21,34,45,17
```

Neither of above is useful to my requirement. I want to be able to store the generated CSV into another column of another table.

### Similar Code for SQL Server:

I used to do this in SQL Server using the following code.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CreateCSV] (@MyXML XML) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX);
    SELECT 
            @listStr = 
                COALESCE(@listStr+',' ,'') + 
                c.value('@Value[1]','nvarchar(max)') 
        FROM @myxml.nodes('/row') as T(c)
    RETURN @listStr
END
```

In SQL Server, I would generate the CSV by calling the CreatCsv() function within a stored procedure. I am trying to replicate the process in postgresql.

I must admit i am new to PostgreSQL so i need your help in this.

Appreciate a helpful response.

Thanks

Steve

Comment: [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) but it looks like you are simply looking for `string_agg()`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name

Turns out i needed

```
SELECT string_agg(id,',') FROM (Select cast (id as varchar(100)) From product limit 10) AS tab;
```

Thanks for helping me with that. :)